# Creating a matching braces highlighter(Like a Code Editor) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am building a widget like piece for webpage in which a user will type his code and I need to implement the brace highlighter on it.
so if a user types

```
 if(a == b)
```

the braces around a and b should be highlighted with a color indicating the scope.
When a user will click around any of these brackets,the other bracket and that bracket it self will be highlighted and same will happen when a user types in and a set of bracket is completed.

For this I am using a **contenteditable** div and using the **window.getSelection()** to determine if the character which was clicked/focused on was a brace and then wrapping span tag around it to give it a color.

I am using **innerHTML** to set the new HTML inside the div with colored brace,but the focus is reset to the start of the div.

I wanted it to behave like a generic code editor.

Any ideas/directions or some other approach are welcomed.

Regards.

Comment: Don't use `innerHTML`, use DOM manipulation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement Lexical Analysis in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726539/how-to-implement-lexical-analysis-in-javascript)

Comment: @FelixKling please give an example?

Comment: Does that means any other way to change the brace without using innerHTML? @FelixKling

Comment: using `.innerHTML` is technically DOM. But I think what he means is maybe create a text node perhaps. Check this out: http://codemirror.net/ @techie_28