# Remove an object from JSON using RegEx

Tags: regex, lexical-analysis

I have JSON objects in this format:

```
 {
     "1f626": {
         "name": "frowning face with open mouth",
         "ascii": [],
         "code_points": {
             "base": "1f626",
             "default_matches": [
                 "1f626"
             ],
             "greedy_matches": [
                 "1f626"
             ],
             "decimal": ""
         }
     }
 }
```

I have to remove the `code_points` object using **Regular Expressions**.

---

I have tried using this RegEx:

```
(("code\w+)(.*)(}))
```

But it is only selecting the first line.
I have to select until end of curly brackets in order to fully get rid of the `code_points` object.

How can I do that?

---

Note: I have to remove it using Regular Expressions and not JavaScript.
Please don't post any JavaScript answers or mark this as a possible duplicate of a JavaScript-based question.

Comment: Just `delete obj["1f626"]["code_points"]`

Comment: @KaiserKatze using javascript?

Comment: Yes. Just try `delete obj["1f626"]["code_points"]`, with `obj` being the object in your code.

Comment: Reference: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485127/how-to-delete-unset-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object); [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object); [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596782/how-to-unset-a-javascript-variable).

Comment: I have to remove using `Regular Expression` not JavaScript

Comment: If so, you are asking for [Lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Tokenization) feature.

Comment: JSON isn't a regular language; it is actually awful to use regex on JSON and it is why we have JSON parsers. I dread to think who is forcing you to use regex :-(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement Lexical Analysis in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726539/how-to-implement-lexical-analysis-in-javascript).

Comment: If you have to do it without javascript, maybe the javascript tag on the question isn't appropriate?

Comment: I hope you understand that **JSON encoder/decoder is not written in Regular Expression**.

Comment: @Mina You could choose to use a [**JSON encoder/decoder written in C/C++**](https://json.org/).

Comment: this is a large JSON file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/delowar64/emoji-finder/master/src/emoji/emoji.json
I have to reduce file size, that's why I want to use  Regular expression.
@KaiserKatze

Comment: @Mina I don't understand why you choose not to use JavaScript. Efficiency?

Comment: @KaiserKatze if I use javascript method then how can get output value as a new file content?

Comment: @Mina If you use JavaScript to handle JSON, you should learn to use [**Node.js**](https://nodejs.org/en/), which is a standalone JavaScript Engine.

Comment: @Mina You could try to use [**Python**](https://www.python.org) to handle JSON as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, at the command-line, if you can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/#)

```
jq "del(.[].code_points)" <monster.json >smaller_monster.json
```

This deletes the `code_points` key inside each 2nd-level object.

It took my machine about 5 seconds on a 60MB document.

It's not a regular expression but it's not JavaScript, either. So, it meets half of your non-functional requirements.

Comment: thanks for your answer, this code also removing object key & comma: http://prntscr.com/knh22y   here is code snippet: https://jqplay.org/s/ohqeX8OnG_

Comment: can you please help me about this?

Comment: @Mina. Weird. I fixed the query.

Answer (score 1):

`("code_points")([\s\S]*?)(})`

The problem you had is that `.` is actually any character except `\n`, so in this case I usually use `[\s\S]` which means any whitespace and non-whitespace character (so it's actually any character). Also you should make `*` quantifier to be lazy by adding `?`.

**Remember that this Regular Expression won't work properly in case you have inner object (other `{}`) in `code_points`**